# Divergence of $\iint \text e^{-(\tau_1-\tau_2)}\,\theta(\tau_1-\tau_2)\,\text d ^2\tau$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does this integral ($\alpha>0$)
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\text d \tau_1 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\text d \tau_2 \; \text e^{-\alpha(\tau_1-\tau_2)}\theta(\tau_1-\tau_2)
$$
diverge? Here $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

My intuition says no. But my result says that it does diverge.

I calculate it in the following way:
$$
I=\int_A \text d^2\tau\; \text e^{-\alpha(\tau_1-\tau_2)}\;,
$$
where $A=\{(\tau_1,\tau_2)\,|\,\tau_1-\tau_2>0\}$. Then I introduced new coordinates
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\tau_1-\tau_2 \\ \tau_1+\tau_2
\end{pmatrix}\;,
$$
such that
$$
I=\int_{0}^\infty\text d x \int_{-\infty}^\infty\text d y \; \text e^{-\sqrt 2 \alpha x}\;.
$$
This is clearly divergent. Is that correct?

Comment: what is the function $\theta$

Comment: It is the Heaviside step function. Sorry...

Comment: You could directly compute each inner integral in the very first formula.

Comment: But how? Because of the Heaviside step function the integrals are not independent, or?

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\text d \tau_2 \; \text e^{-\alpha(\tau_1-\tau_2)}\theta(\tau_1-\tau_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\tau_1}\text d \tau_2 \; \text e^{-\alpha(\tau_1-\tau_2)}\stackrel{t=\tau_1-\tau_2}{=}\int_{0}^\infty\text d t \; \text e^{-\alpha t}=\frac1{\alpha}$$

Comment: All right! Thanks. Sometimes it is so easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $f(x)$ as the function $e^{-ax}u(x)$. Let $g(x)$ be a function that equals to $1$ everywhere. Then $I=\int d\tau_1 (g*f)(\tau_1)$. The convolution is equal to
$(g*f)(x)=\int f(x-\tau_2) d\tau_2=\int f(\tau_2)d\tau_2=\int_0^\infty e^{-a\tau_2}d\tau_2=1/a$. 
Then, $I=\int d\tau_1 (1/a)=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx=\infty$.